# How can I extend this function (edit button) on JavaScript within Odoo?

Tags: javascript, edit, odoo-9, odoo

I would like to create a module which controls edit button on certain conditions. I tried the following code in js but I got no effect. So I would like to know how to extend a function in js.

```
formView.include({
    init:function(){

        var edits = new Model('sale.order');
        edits.query(['validity_date']);
        console.log(validity_date)
        },
    on_button_edit: function(){
        this._super();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this in the js file. I wrote some examples to help you.

```javascript
openerp.custom_edit_button = function (instance) {
    var _t = instance.web._t;   

    instance.web.FormView.include({
        init: function() {
            console.log('JS loaded')  
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);   
        },  

        to_edit_mode: function(){
            // examples of useful methods
            var field_values = this.get_fields_values();
            var ids = this.get_selected_ids();
            var id = field_values['id'];
            var date = field_values['date'];
            var model = this.model;

            console.log(field_values)
            console.log(ids)
            console.log(id)
            console.log(model)
            console.log(date)
            console.log(Date.today())

            date_to_compare = new Date(date);
            console.log(date_to_compare)

            if(date_to_compare < Date.today()){
                error = this.error;
                var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;
                var dialog = new instance.web.Dialog(this, { 
                    title: _t("Set new expiry date"), 
                    width: '30%', 
                    size: 'medium',
                    /*dialogClass: 'oe_act_window',*/
                    buttons: [ 
                          { text: _t("OK"), click: function() { self.set_new_expiry_date(); }}, 
                          { text: _t("Close"), click: function() { dialog.close(); return; }
                          },                          
                      ],
                }, QWeb.render('custom_edit_button.expiry_date_form', {error: error})).open();

            }

            this._super();
        }
    });
}
```

So, if the expiry date is in the past, the form is going to appear to change it. You must define the method `set_new_expiry_date` as well. And on the other hand you must add this template, or something similar to show the form. Add the file in the qweb section of your `__openerp__.py`

```xml
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <div t-name="custom_edit_button.expiry_date_form" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="date" class="control-label">New expiry date:</label>
            <input name="date" class="form-control"/>
        </div>   
    </div>
</templates>
```

Notice that the name of my module is `custom_edit_button` in the example

Comment: thanks for replying what i am trying is Based on existing expiry date(`validity_date`) field on `sale.order`, enable edit mode only if the  expiry date exceeds current date .

Comment: Mmm I think you can't do that because you don't have the id of the record when the edit button appears. Another option is to use the `attrs` attribute in each field or group or fields.

Comment: the problem here is i can't update date.My idea is,if current date exceeds, then open a wizard to enter a new  expiry date. The edit button is js (addons/web/static/src/js/form_view.js)

Comment: Are you sure that you can't change the date? If you use the `attrs` attribute you can update the date only if the condition is satisfied

Comment: formView.include({
    on_button_edit: function() {
    return this.to_edit_mode();
    },
    to_edit_mode: function() {
        this._super();
        }

    });

Comment: @111sree I changed my answer. Check if now is useful for you